# extract sublist of concrect product from a list of abstract product

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, jung

[image]

I construct an Hyper graph using [jung](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) library

```
  Hypergraph hypergraph = new SetHyperGraph<Vertex,HyperEdge>();
```

then I add all my vertex (image , tag , location)

```
    hypergraph.addVertex()

    ArrayList<Vertex> allVertex = hypergraph.getVertices;
```

Now I would to extract only image Vertex from  my list`allVertex`

why this instruction is illegal?

```
    ArrayList<ImageVertex> allImageList=allVertex.subList(0,j);
```

Does Anyone have another solution?

Comment: Because `allVertex` may also contain `TagVertex` and `ImageVertex` and java is unable to figure it out at the compile time.

Comment: Use for loop with instanceof. Btw, tarrsalah answered the question much clearer than I did.

Comment: What does the word "concrect" mean in the title?

Comment: As it is shown in the uml diagram 
abstract product=`Vertex `
and concret peoduct are `Image`,`tag`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a sample code

```
List<ImageVertex> allImageList = new ArrayList<ImageVertex>();
for (Vertex vertex : allVertex) {
  if (vertex instanceof ImageVertex) {
    allImageList.add((ImageVertex) vertex);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `ArrayList<ImageVertex>` is not a [subtype](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html) of `ArrayList<Vertex>`.

possible solution will be :

```
ArrayList<ImageVertex> allImageList= new ArrayList<>();

for (Vertex vertex: allVertex.sublist(0,j)) {
    if (vertex instanceof ImageVertex) {
        allImageList.add((ImageVertex) vertex);
    }
}
```

Comment: try to loop throw all the `Vertex` list, and get the `ImageVertx` elements using the `instanceof` method.

Comment: I believe that j is amount of ImageVertex, but it seems that nawara wants to extract all image vertexes. Also, please add cast to `ImageVertex`.

Comment: j is number of all my Image Vertex 
in fact mu idea is to sort `allVertex` alphabetically (image->location->tag)
then as i know `j` value , i extract the first `j` vertex from `allVertex` list

Comment: Alright, so you might use this approach or simply use single for-each loop instead of sort, sublist and loop.